# Flexslider startAt option and directionNav seem to conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, flexslider

I am using Flexslider 2.0 with the startAt option on the last slide.

This seems to mess up the directional navigation.

Anybody had this issue before and knows how to solve it?

The code I am using with nothing really special:

```
    $(".period-slides").flexslider({
      animation: "slide", 
      animationLoop: false,
      itemWidth: 265,
      minItems: 4,
      maxItems: 4,
      controlNav: false,
      directionNav: true,
      prevText: "\ue75d",
      nextText: "\ue75e"
      startAt: 7
    });
```

EDIT: Html added

```
<div class="period-slides">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li class="slide"><!-- repeated 8 times -->
      <div class="period-overview">
        <p>Some Content</p>
      </div>  
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

EDIT: It doesn't seem to have a proper indication of at what position in currently is, seems like in the navigation the current position is the first slide. So I when setting the startAt it doesn't set the navigation properly.

Comment: What do you mean by "mess up the directional navigation"? Is it the way clicking the next arrow scrolls the slider back to the first slide despite `animationLoop: false`?

Comment: It doesn't seem to have a proper indication of at what position in currently is, seems like in the navigation the current position is the first slide. So I when setting the startAt it doesn't set the navigation properly.

Comment: Could you perhaps post the HTML that goes with the JS? I ask because I modified one of the samples that comes with Flexslider and was able to set `startAt` just fine.

Comment: @nick_w I updated the question with the html I am using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on that HTML in your edit, you have 8 items in total which will be split into two slides of four.

I think the problem you are having is that setting `startAt` to 7 is too high - you only have two slides, so the index will need to be either 1 or 0.

When I set `startAt` to 7 the slider initially appeared blank and I had to navigate backward to get the final slide to appear. Setting `startAt` to 1 or 0 caused the correct slide to be displayed initially.

Comment: When I look at the index in the web inspector it shows a list of 8 li's, not 2 seperate lists.

Comment: So what happened when you set `startAt` to 0 or 1? I just tried in Chrome and FF and a value of 7 stopped the navigation working at all, but 0 or 1 was fine.